# A geometrical criterion for differentiability?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$ s.t. $f\left(0\right)=0$
, let $\text{graph}\left(f\right)=\left\{ \left(v,f\left(v\right)\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^{m}|v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\right\}$ let
$U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^{m}$ a vector subspace with
$\dim U=n$ let $U^{\perp}$be the orthogonal subspace to $U$ and
let $P_{U}$ and $P_{U^{\perp}}$ be the orthogonal projections. suppose
$$
\lim_{v\to0}\frac{P_{U^{\perp}}\left(\left(v,f\left(v\right)\right)\right)}{\|{P_{U}\left(v,f\left(v\right)\right)}\|}=0
$$
is $f$ differential and $U$ the tangent space of the graph? Does it help if $f$ is continuous?  the motivation for this is the fact that the converse holds.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$ s.t. $f\left(0\right)=0$
be differentiable at $0$ let $U=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}v\\
Df\left(0\right)\cdot v
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^{m}|v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\right\} $ let $P_{U}$ be the orthogonal projection on $U$ then 
$$
\lim_{v\to0}\frac{P_{U^{\perp}}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}}{\|P_{U}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|}=0
$$
 geometrically this means that the angle of the graph of $f$ with
the tangent space vanishes as $v\to0.$ Proof : We show now that there
is a constant $C$ s.t. $C\|v\|\le\|P_{U}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|$ . 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\|P_{U}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|^{2}}{\|v\|^{2}} & = & \frac{\|\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|^{2}}{\|v\|^{2}}-\frac{\|\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}-P_{U}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|^{2}}{\|v\|^{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}
we notice that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\|\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|^{2}}{\|v\|^{2}} & = & \frac{1}{\|v\|^{2}}\left(\|v\|^{2}+\|f\left(v\right)\|^{2}\right)\\
 & = & 1+\frac{\|f\left(v\right)\|^{2}}{\|v\|^{2}}\\
 & \ge & 1+\frac{1}{\|v\|^{2}}\left|\|Df\left(0\right)v\|-\|f\left(v\right)-Df\left(0\right)v\|\right|^{2}\\
 & \ge & 1+\left(\frac{\|Df\left(0\right)v\|}{\|v\|}\right)^{2}+\frac{\|f\left(v\right)-Df\left(0\right)v\|^{2}}{\|v\|^{2}}-2\frac{\|Df\left(0\right)v\|}{\|v\|}\frac{\|f\left(v\right)-Df\left(0\right)v\|}{\|v\|}
\end{eqnarray*}
the sphere is compact so $C\ge\frac{\|Df\left(0\right)v\|}{\|v\|}\ge0$
and there is a neighborhood of $0$ s.t. $\frac{\|f\left(v\right)-Df\left(0\right)v\|}{\|v\|}\le\frac{1}{4C}$
so 
$$
\frac{\|\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|^{2}}{\|v\|^{2}}\ge\frac{1}{2}
$$
 and for the right neighborhood 
$$
\frac{\|\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}-P_{U}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|^{2}}{\|v\|^{2}}\le\frac{\|f\left(v\right)-Df\left(0\right)v\|^{2}}{\|v\|^{2}}\le\min\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{16c^{2}}\right)
$$
 this gives 
$$
\frac{\|P_{U}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|^{2}}{\|v\|^{2}}\ge\frac{1}{4}
$$
 so 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\|v\|\le\|P_{U}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|
$$
 Now 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\|P_{U^{\perp}}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|}{\|P_{U}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|} & = & \frac{\|\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}-P_{U}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|}{\|P_{U}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|}\\
 & \le & \frac{\|\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}v\\
Df\left(0\right)\cdot v
\end{pmatrix}\|}{\|P_{U}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|}\\
 & = & \frac{\|f\left(v\right)-Df\left(0\right)\cdot v\|}{\|P_{U}\begin{pmatrix}v\\
f\left(v\right)
\end{pmatrix}\|}\\
 & \le & \frac{\|f\left(v\right)-Df\left(0\right)v\|}{\frac{1}{2}\|v\|}\to0
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Clearly $U$ should not be a "vertical" subspace.